# how can i send a json+ld schema.org email to myself in gmail

Tags: gmail, schema.org, google-schemas

gmail recently announced schema.org support for in-app and one-click actions. They note that one can immediately test out the schema by sending an email from oneself to oneself i.e. from  x@gmail.com to x@gmail.com (1)

My question is how do i send an email with the json+ld schema.org markup - I can only send text and/or html and if i try to send using mailgun / sendgrid etc. than the email won't be from x@gmail.com

So, how do i test this??

(1) https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/registering-with-google

Comment: https://github.com/googleknowledge/GmailActions and http://gmail-actions.appspot.com/ may also be useful for those just trying to test out there.  I had tested using the gmailapi but it didn't work but the ones mentioned in the previous one worked for me.

Comment: did you manage to make it works? please if so let me know! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962810/gmail-email-markup-not-working-even-for-personal-gmail-account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many options, three that come into my mind right now are:

1. use the Apps Script [Gmail service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/), as shown in our [Apps Script quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/apps-script-tutorial)
2. use App Engine as in the [end-to-end example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/actions/end-to-end-example) in the documentation
3. connect to Gmail via SMTP to send emails from there

Comment: The docs say *@gmail.com to *@gmail.com should work now. Can those just be via SMTP with auth? I wasn't able to get it to work using the metadata description via SMTP or by using SPF domain that is used with MandrillApp, but I wasn't able to get the result either.

Comment: *@gmail.com to *@gmail.com should work if you are sending them via Gmail, who will sign them for you. What entities/action are you trying to implement? Can you add your markup or the source of the email that you are sending to the question?

Comment: Apps Script using MailApp.SendEmail with htmlBody having the sample script does not seem to work. I receive the email but unable to see the actions. Will try the App Engine example next.

Comment: I have a working Apps Script sample that uses MailApp.SendEmail, I plan to add it to the docs today or tomorrow.

Comment: FYI, as reported in the reference guide (https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/reference/review-action), the ReviewAction is not available yet

Comment: @ClaudioCherubino I understand that the ReviewAction is not available yet, I'm looking for a working Apps Script sample. Would be great if you could post it.

Comment: The Apps Script tutorial is now available at https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/apps-script-tutorial

Comment: the action button works as charm but the reservation for example not... can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962810/gmail-email-markup-not-working-even-for-personal-gmail-account