# Inline Microdata in Email not showing although correct

Tags: schema.org, google-schemas

So I added the inline microdata to the first two articles of our newsletter (schema.org type Article) and tested it with the Email markup tester. It showed no errors and the data was analyzed correctly. When I send the newsletter to my gmail address, I don't get the summary box that I should get with microdata enabled emails. Any help?

The online version of my email can be found here: https://yz.emsecure.net/optiext/optiextension.dll?ID=Ji6eGRCbfS1Th6QKQlY_yrcy7KZDmJiS0s8nTPf1pfoyKcwEDzcXggWWbz7%2BVVizUZgCNG0A6DKOdWA721tJJr&_SHOWMAILHEADER=TRUE

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41258309/email-markup-gmail-modifying-the-script-tag-to-add-extra-string-3d

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation:

> You can easily test if your markup is working correctly end-to-end by sending emails to yourself. All emails where the sender and the recipient are the same account ignore the [registration requirements](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google) and can be used for self-testing. 
>   DKIM or SPF authentication is still required for self-testing.
>
> Once the markup is tested end-to-end with this technique and you are ready to launch your integration to production, check [Registering with Google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google) for the next steps.

But I found a related SO post - [Testing microdata in Gmail doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28025004/5995040) that functionality is still missing from Gmail. You can use Apps Script, App Engine to test it as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16578979/5995040) suggested